# Aurelia - Set default value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a drop-down which is populated from a JavaScript array.

```
let a = [90, 95, 99];
```

When I bind this array in the HTML as follows, the initial value is set to 90.

```
<select>
    <option repeat.for="i of a">${i}</option>
</select>
```

But I need to show '95' as the default value. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the value of the select to a certain value, which it will take as default.

```
let a = [90, 95, 99];
let selectedValue = 95;
```

Html:

```
<select value.bind="selectedValue">
    <option repeat.for="i of a">${i}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!. I've already found the solution and applied it to my code :)

Comment: I have same issue and I try this but not work for me.Do you have any suggestions